# Installation of Pycuda in Windows 10 (Python 3.6.5)

Tags: python3, pip

I am using anaconda and Windows 10 virtual machine with Python 3.6.5. I am trying to install pycuda package using this command:

```
pip3 install pycuda
Error: Building wheels for collected packages: pycuda
Building wheel for pycuda (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\anaconda\python.exe' -u -c   
 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'
C:\\Users\\hack\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a1dsshvv\\pycuda 

\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"',open)  (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9r1hq74i' --python-tag cp36:
ERROR: *************************************************************
*** I have detected that you have not run configure.py.
```

And then last error:

```
 TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycuda
```

I also tried using .whl file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
It installs perfectly but when I run this command:

```
 import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
```

It again throws some DLL error.

Comment: Exactly what DLL error?

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem,
with anaconda downloaded:
type in command:

```
    conda install -c free mingw
```

then try:

```
    pip3 install pycuda
```